# Run spark job using oozie java actions

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hadoop2

iam able to run oozie examples with MR and Hive having problem in running oozie with spark.

Iam using spark on yarn, and i want to run the example by using java action in oozie.

After submitting the job iam unable to unable to connect to resource manager, it is attempting to connect rm for several times and job is killing.

In my code iam passing the resource manager adress and port to the spark conf as well.

Any help is highly appreciated !!!

Comment: Why not use a Spark action to run Spark jobs? That way, Oozie takes cares of the dependencies (cf. ShareLibs).

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter my version of oozie is 4.1 which doe not have Spark action so trying with Java action. how can i pass delegation token to my job.

Comment: The token is right there, it should be picked automatically by the Hadoop client from the running Java environment... but it's true that Spark may rebuild its own Java env and nix the token. The way Oozie actions work, you should be able to pick the token explicitly inside the local `job.xml` and/or from an OS env variable. Do some research on these directions.

Comment: And anyway, you should not have to force any Hadoop config property from Spark, because Oozie runs the Spark driver in YARN to begin with, and YARN should put its default client conf in your driver's CLASSPATH -- so it should be picked automagically.